# Using a Launchscreen Storyboard for landscape only

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, launch-screen

I have an app where all Viewcontrollers except 1 are landscape, thats why my Info.plist is configured like this:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Now my problem is, that the app is always launched in portrait first, before the rotation gets set to Landscape in my first Viewcontroller.

How can i fix this? I want my Launchscreen.storyboard to be launched in landscape

Comment: what if you change it in your deployment info ?

Comment: The deployment info actually writes into the Info.plist, so that's covered